# Showing KeyError: 'schedules.tasks.run' while running the django celery for periodic tasks

Tags: scheduled-tasks, django-celery, celerybeat, djcelery, periodic-task

I've created a classes based periodic task using djcelery to send emails to the client. Task is performing the action and sending email when it is called from shell but while using the crontab, I am getting KeyError as "Schedule.tasks.run". I have added the following setting and created the tasks:

## settings.py

```
import os
import djcelery

djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'django://'

BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "guest"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "guest"
BROKER_VHOST = "/"

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
"runs-every-30-seconds": {
    "task": "schedules.tasks.EndingDrawslotScheduler.run",
    "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
    "args": (16, 16)
},
}
app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'

INSTALLED_APPS = ('djcelery',
'kombu.transport.django',)
```

## Error-Info:

The full contents of the message body was:

```
{'utc': True, 'callbacks': None, 'id': '6ad19ff8-9825-4d54-a8b2-0a8322fc9fb1', 
'args': [], 'taskset': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': (None, None), 
'kwargs': {}, 'expires': None, 'errbacks': None, 'chord': None, 'task': 
'schedules.tasks.run', 'eta': None} (262b)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/home/s/proj/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 465, in on_task_received strategies[type_](message, body,
> KeyError: 'schedules.tasks.run'

Comment: It looks like the error message is cut off. Could you reformat and post the whole error message?

Comment: Here is the error which i got :raised unexpected: TypeError('run() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/s/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: run() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given